# If there is list of 4 string elements. Several elements are - separated strings. If I want to print just one part of the - separated word

Tags: python, string, split

```
list2 = ['BIA-660', 'Web', 'Analytics']
```

Question:  How to extract "660" from `list2`

```
list2 = ['BIA-660', 'Web', 'Analytics']
c=list2[0]
x=c.split("-")
print(x[1])
```

I am getting the answer but Wanted to know if there is another more efficient way of achieving the solution.

Comment: I don't think there's anything simpler. You could do it without all the intermediate variables with `print(list2[0].split('-')[1])`

Comment: You can limit the number of splits with a second param of `split` or/and use `rsplit`.  Depends on which of the elements you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regex to get any digits from a string

```
import re

list2 = ['BIA-660', 'Web', 'Analytics']

for strg in list2:
    found = re.findall('\d+', strg)
    if found != []:
        for num in found:
            print(num)
```

Output:

```
660
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain regex is not more efficient then split.

Comment: yes regex may not be more efficient, but it's able to generalize to get digits out of any strings

Answer (score 1):

This will return a list of numbers contained in the string:

```
list2 = ['BIA-660', 'Web', 'Analytics']
s = '-'.join(list2)

# extract numbers from string
result = [int(txt) for txt in s.split('-') if txt.isdigit()]
print(result)

[660]
```

Comment: original code didn't work, so I edited it if you don't mind, cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I find with these things it can be important to get the result but also know where the result came from.  So, all as well as returning the data, it tells where the index it was found at in the input list.

Also takes into account *Several occurences* of -separated items, as well as something like `foo-bar-zoom`.

```
def extractor(li : list[str]) -> list[tuple[str,int]]:

    res = []
    for ix, v in enumerate(li):
        if "-" in v:
            found = v.split('-',maxsplit=1)[1]
            res.append((found,ix))

    return res
```

Some runs:

```
✅! 
extractor for ['BIA-660', 'Web', 'Analytics']                                                                      
exp :[('660', 0)]:
got :[('660', 0)]:

✅! 
extractor for ['BIA-660', 'Web-3.0', 'Analytics']                                                                  
exp :[('660', 0), ('3.0', 1)]:
got :[('660', 0), ('3.0', 1)]:

✅! 
extractor for ['BIA-660', 'foo-bar-zoom']                                                                          
exp :[('660', 0), ('bar-zoom', 1)]:
got :[('660', 0), ('bar-zoom', 1)]:
```

You could extend it to ignore list items that are not strings (`isinstance(v,str)`) and extracted values that are not numbers (check that `float(found)` succeeds).